# How to use variable in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

var result;var response;var jsonString ;var msg;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xhrPost = new XMLHttpRequest();

function xhrGetCall(getUrl){
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          result = xhr.responseText;
          jsonString = JSON.parse(result);
          console.log('API data retrieved:'+jsonString);
          return result;
      }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', getUrl, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
  xhr.send(null);
  xhr.onerror = function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log( 'The data failed to load :('+JSON.stringify(xhr));
  };
};

function xhrPostCall(jsonInput, postUrl){

  xhrPost.open("POST",postUrl, true);
  xhrPost.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhrPost.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhrPost.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhrPost.status == 200) {
        msg="succesful!";
          console.log('posting succesful'+jsonInput);
      }
            else {
            msg="failed!";
            alert('msg is:'+msg);
            console.log('posting unsuccesful'+msg);
            }
  }
  xhrPost.send(jsonInput);
    return msg;
}

class AddDetailsModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {UserName: ''};
        this.handleChangeUserName = this.handleChangeUserName.bind(this);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);

        xhrGetCall(this.props.getUrl);
        xhr.onload = function() {
         response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
         this.setState({apiReturnValue:jsonToHtmlSelect(response)});
     }.bind(this);
  }
    componentDidMount(){

    }
    handleChangeUserName(event) {
    this.setState({UserName: event.target.value});
  }


  handleSubmit(event) {
        var str = {"UserName": this.state.UserName};
        var json = JSON.stringify(str);
    xhrPostCall(json,this.props.postUrl);
        this.setState({msg:xhrPostCall()});
        console.log("testing: msg:"+msg);

        $('#AddDetailsModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this)
    .find("input,textarea")
       .val('')
       .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
       .prop("checked", "")
       .end();
         })


  }

  render() {

    return (
            <div>
            <div id="AddDetailsModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 className="modal-title">Add Details</h4>
                  </div>

            <div className="modal-body">

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="col-sm-0 control-label" htmlFor="textinput"> Name : &nbsp; </label>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.UserName} onChange={this.handleChangeUserName}  placeholder="Name" className="form-control"></input>
        </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                  <button type="submit" value="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#AddMsgModal">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="AddMsgModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">

            <div className="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 className="modal-title">Message Heading</h4>
                </div>

                <div className="alert alert-success">
                {msg}
                </div>

    <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

 </div>


    );
  }
}


export default AddDetailsModal;
```

I have made a react component "AddDetailsModal" which is bootstrap form modal on successful or unsuccessful submission of the form by handleSubmit() function the other modal "AddMsgModal" should come up showing the msg.

i am not able to access the msg variable declared in function xhrPostCall in the render() of react js.

Kindly let me know how to access that variable there?

Comment: you need to add the msg variable in the component's properties during the declaration `<AddDetailsModal msg={msg}>` then in your component you can access it in your render function via `this.props.msg`

Comment: can u explain a bit more ?

Comment: AddDetailsModal form is a form on the submission of which I open AddMsgModal and display this {msg} into this modal.

Answer (score 0):

**First** - use a library like [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fetch), to create some ajax requests.

**Second** -  if you want to create it by yourself use `Promise` to create async operations:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //perform some async actions
    resolve(result)
})
```

Then in components:

```
fetchData().then((result) => this.setState({msg: result})
```