# ReactJs siblings component

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, siblings

So I am trying to access a variable msg declared in a component AddFormDetails in its sibling component AddMsgModal.

But not able to access it, I am getting an error:msg is not defined.

Kindly explain how to access a variable in sibling component of ReactJS.

AddFormDetails and AddMsgModal are child elements of parent component called App.

Comment: you need to move variable `msg` up to `App` state and pass it down to `AddFormDetails` and `AddMsgModal`

Comment: I am using this msg varaible in a function declared in AddFormDetails which is triggered by a click of a button.

Comment: it still gives the same error

Comment: i am now accessing the msg varaible in AddMsgModal with the help of this.props.msg is it okay?

Comment: Please share some code that you have tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891113/how-to-use-variable-in-react-js

Comment: i had asked a question previously..changes now I have made is I have taken the AddMsgModal div and made it a separate React component as a whole

Comment: use any one: either store the msg in store n fetch it inside another component, or use props, pass a function from App to 1st component, then from 1st com pass the msg to parent then from parent pass it to 2nd component.

Comment: lift up `msg` and related function  to `App` and pass it down